# Time series data to measure the effect of an intervention on inpatient utilization

Tags: time-series, intervention-analysis

I have a general knowledge of regression, but I don't know what is the best approach to analyze these data. The dataset represents quarterly rates of inpatient use for three provider groups `prov1`, `prov2` and `prov3`. The rates were measured on quarterly basis from `qrt-4 2005` until `qrt-3 2012`. On the 3rd qrt of 2008 an intervention was implemented by provider groups `1` and `2`, provider `3` represents all other providers of a network that did not participate of the intervention; so this is our control group. The purpose of this project is to measure the effect of the intervention between the before and after periods and between the participating and non-participating providers. Here is an example of the data:

```
Qrt-Yr  Period  Prov1   prov2   Prov3
Q4-2005 Before  103.4   201.1   189.9
Q1-2006 Before  175.4   224.2   184.5
Q2-2006 Before  140.2   237.3   187.7
Q3-2006 Before  196.8   255.6   183.5
Q4-2006 Before  222.1   204.7   187.7
Q1-2007 Before  172.5   212.5   189.7
Q2-2007 Before  172.7   207.9   185.9
Q3-2007 Before  128.8   214.7   192.9
Q4-2007 Before  164.9   197.7   205.5
Q1-2008 Before  172.1   225.9   210.3
Q2-2008 Before  103.9   209.3   203.1
Q3-2008 Before  151.1   223.7   211.4
Q4-2008 After   200.8   234.3   189.6
Q1-2009 After   158.1   185.6   206.8
Q2-2009 After   103.8   218.2   187.9
Q3-2009 After   132.7   204.6   202.5
Q4-2009 After   178.7   218.7   191.3
Q1-2010 After   181.0   223.6   178.4
Q2-2010 After   119.9   203.2   191.3
Q3-2010 After   144.6   228.7   193.8
Q4-2010 After   87.2    161.0   173.1
Q1-2011 After   102.4   178.7   175.8
Q2-2011 After   151.0   173.4   169.9
Q3-2011 After   137.1   233.9   187.5
Q4-2011 After   83.0    226.6   164.3
Q1-2012 After   147.6   193.7   172.0
Q2-2012 After   103.8   163.5   171.7
Q3-2012 After   159.1   180.8   172.5
Q4-2012 After   133.1   155.1   160.7
```

Answer (score 1):

I do recommend you reconstruct your data as "retail month" data instead of quarterly so you will have enough time points for a good analysis.  A retail month is a constant 28 days long and controls for the fact that the number of weekend days varies across months introducing a systematic component that would need to be modeled.